# How to transform this pseudocode to M language?

Tags: excel, powerquery

[source link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IRCusJfyDTieoAw00icpn3G-OrKrEz_u/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=105242488633957727126&rtpof=true&sd=true)

Hi,  so I have  2 tables (need and supply) like this:

[image]

I am trying to add a custom column on the need table where for each item I want to retrieve the appropriate supply date based on the following condition (pseudocode) :

```
if
     supply(Qty) >=  need(Qty) and  (supply(Supply date) <> null  and |supply(Supply date) - need(Date)| < 31 days) 
     then supply(Supply date)

else   
     if  
        supply(Supply date) = null
                then "NO"
         else 
        "NON2"
```

Here's what  I started doing:

```
 x = Table.Column(source, Table.SelectRows(supply, each supply([Qty]) >=  need([Qty]) and  (supply[Supply date] <> null  and ((supply([Supply date]) =< Date.AddMonths(need([Date]),1)  or (supply([Supply date]) >= Date.AddMonths(need([Date]),-1))  )),Supply([date]),
 if x <> null then x else "NO2"
```

Obviously I don't get what I want, that's why I come here asking for your help. Thx

Answer (score 0):

Supply is a table. How can I apply **Supply(Supply date) = null then "NO"** to an entire table?

That said, see if this helps at all

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Item", type any}, {"Date", type datetime}, {"Qty", Int64.Type}}),
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Changed Type", {"Item"}, supply, {"item"}, "supply", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Custom", each 

let ThisDate=[Date], ThisQty=[Qty] in try Table.SelectRows( [supply], each [Qty]>ThisQty and [Supply date]<>null
and  Number.From([Supply date]) - Number.From(ThisDate)<31)[Supply date]{0} otherwise "NON")

in #"Added Custom"
```